# Not able to take name input from using input field

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-context

```
<Modal
     centered
     show={props?.show}
     contentClassName="bg-white"
     size="xl"
     tabIndex="10"
   >
     <Modal.Header className="bg-white px-4 py-3 ">
       <div className="text-center w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
         <div className="fw-600 text-uppercase">
           Enter Your Name To Continue
         </div>
       </div>
       <CloseButton onClick={props?.onHide} className={`modalCloseBtn p-0`} />
     </Modal.Header>
     <Modal.Body className="p-0 border border-top-0 border-2 rounded-bottom">
       <Form className={`bg-white p-1 text-white`}>
         <Form.Group
           controlId="formName"
           className="col-md-12 p-4 align-items-center"
         >
           {/* <Form.Label className="col-md-3">Name:</Form.Label> */}
           <Form.Control
             type="text"
             placeholder="Enter your name"
             // tabIndex={200}
             onChange={(e) =>
               // setName(e.target.value)
               contextValue.setName(e.target.value)
             }
             // value={contextValue.name}
             // readOnly={false}
             // disabled={false}
             required
           />
         </Form.Group>
       </Form>
     </Modal.Body>
     <Modal.Footer>
       <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.onHide}>
         Close
       </Button>
       <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
         Submit
       </Button>
     </Modal.Footer>
   </Modal>
```

I am taking input using above code,but i am not able to type anything in the field . I have also ensured the tabIndex of this modal is greater than other , i have tried it using  readOnly={false}, disabled={false} but nothing worked.

Comment: `// value={contextValue.name}` is commented out

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/forms/form-control#formcontrol